# Fail to load Chromium with URL

Tags: retropie, chromium

I'm currently struggling to get chromium-browser start with a predefined url.

I have a script running this :

> startx chromium-browser

That works fine to start Chromium with X, but why can't I specify any argument to chromium-browser ?? I was thinking of something like that :

> startx chromium-browser --app=http://my.predefined.url

That just won't work (even if I specify only the url whithout the app mode). when I look to the code, it seems that --app=URL is recognized as a startx argument and not as a chromium-browser argument.

My linux knowledge is limited, and I did'nt find any solution. Can somebody help me ?

I'm running Retropie 2.6 (debian)

Comment: *"when I look to the code, it seems that --app=URL is recognized as a startx argument and not as a chromium-browser argument."* -> When you look at what code?!?  By my reading of `man startx`, this should pass the option to the client app (chromium browser).

Comment: Does `startx "chromium-browser --app=http://my.predefined.url"` work?

Answer (score 2):

There are for sure more elegant ways to do this, but if your URL is fixed, you can make a short bash script (`nano /home/pi/startbrowser.sh`) with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
chromium-browser --app=http://my.predefined.url
```

Make sure the file is executable (`chmod 744 /home/pi/startbrowser.sh`) and then you can issue

```
startx /home/pi/startbrowser.sh
```

To start chromium with the url you specified.

Comment: Thanks, that is an improvement but still not ok : I think emulationstation is causing X some issues. If i launch startx /home/pi/startbrowser.sh it work, but if put this into a script (with chmod 755), the script do load chromium at the right url but, but cause a "stuck in blank screen" isssue (it can't load any page nor settings page). I'm still trying to find out how to run it whithout this bug, using a script.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used midori following the steps of [this post](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Digital-Signage-Exchange-Rate-Display/step13/Start-the-Midori-browser-in-full-screen-mode/)

and everything is now okay.